# Validate value where another column's value for the record is in array of values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Input to be validated is a tree where a subcategory is valid, only if its' parent category has been selected too.

The input values are as follows:

```php
$categories = [1,2,3];
```

```php
//in database, each subcategory has column "category_id"
$sub_categories = [4,5,6]
```

Validation

```php
$this->validate([
 "sub_categories.*" => [
  "exists:sub_categories,id",
  //Rule for checking that the category_id for this subcategory
  //exists in the categories array.
 ]
])
```

Is there such a built in laravel rule or do I need to write the rule myself?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Rule` class

```
Validation

$this->validate([
    "sub_categories.*" => [
        "exists:sub_categories,id", 
        \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::in($categories),
    ],
])
```

Comment: This would check whether the id of the sub_category in question exists in the array of the categories. I went with something like this:

```php
Rule::exists('sub_categories', 'id')->where(function($query) {
 $query->whereIn('category_id', $categories);
})
```

Comment: @Jacobdo where are you getting the Ids from ?